# Рефакторинг Sql-запроса (Postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Всем доброго дня! Вопрос следующий:
Имеются 3 таблицы:

| Users |
| --- |
| id |
| name |

| Shops |
| --- |
| id |

| Users_Shops |
| --- |
| user_id |
| shop_id |

Отношения между таблицами Users и Shops многие-ко-многим через таблицу Users_Shops

Например, в таблице Shops - 5 магазинов, с id 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
Пользователь добавил в свой список магазины с id 2, 3

Как получить id магазинов, которых нет в списке пользователя?

Сейчас использую такой sql:

`SELECT * FROM Shops WHERE id != (SELECT shop_id From Users_Shops WHERE user_id = $1)`

Это работает, но получается я делаю 2 запроса в БД, можно ли как-то обойтись одним?

Спасибо за Ваши ответы!

Comment: Почему вы говорите, что делаете два запроса? (Один) запрос, который вы привели, делает то, что вы описали.

Comment: А Select, который выполняется 2 раза не означает, что в базу стучатся 2 раза?

Comment: Из вашего вопроса непонятно, о каком втором запросе идет речь. В вопросе один запрос на получение магазинов, которых нет в списке пользователя. Может вы говорите о том, что этот запрос содержит подзапрос `SELECT shop_id From Users_Shops WHERE user_id = $1`? Это часть запроса, а не отдельный запрос. В базу идет один вызов и выполняется один запрос даже если в нем есть подзапрос.